# How to reset a quasar q-form from a method

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am curious how to reset a q-form when the submit action is triggered. I run a function onSubmit but I am not sure how in that method to reset the q-form without having to do each field individually which is annoying. Here is my code:

```
      //methods
  const onSubmit = (event) => { 
    let jsonData = 
  {
    FirstName: firstName.value,
    LastName: lastName.value,
    PhoneNumber: phoneNumber.value,
    EmailAddress: emailAddress.value,
    Message: message.value,
    Token: token.value
  }

api.post('/api/contactus', jsonData)
.then((response) => {
  
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('API request failed')
})
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/form#usage) has an example of exactly what you want

```js
// <q-form ref="myForm">

// to reset validations:
function reset () {
  myForm.value.resetValidation()
}
```

or Options API:

```js
this.$refs.myForm.resetValidation()
```

This function is shown in the documentation as being tied to a "Reset" button but there's no reason you can't use it after submitting as well.